# Why isn't ipfw correctly limiting the bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth-control, osx-lion, ipfw

I've played around with the ipfw command on a Mac and tried to limit the bandwidth to 1MBit/s.

```
sudo ipfw add pipe 1 ip from any to me
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 1MBit/s
```

These are the statements I'm using. ipfw indeed limits the bandwidth drastically but according to speedtest.net only to ~7.7 Mbps on a 100 Mbps line. With a restriction to 3MBit/s the effective download is ~23.13 Mbps. Apparently the ipfw always uses a factor ~7.7 of the given limit. With a limit of 4 Mbps the effective speed is ~30,84 Mbps, with 8 Mbps it's ~61.6 Mbps and so on...

Anyone knows why this is the reason? Is it a bug or do I use the statement wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I'm also interested if anyone else can reproduce this or if it's an issue on my side.

Comment: Can you `sudo ipfw show` here?

Comment: @Kondybas

`radi:~ Phil$ sudo ipfw show`
`00100 2046813 1042400871 pipe 1 ip from any to me`
`00200 2223777  296348885 pipe 2 ip from me to any`
`65535 7182907 2143167607 allow ip from any to any`
aargh.. didn't manage to properly use the code tags

Comment: other then creating a pipe itself you need to specify which traffic goes through that pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your IPFW treat `bw xMBits` as `xMBytes` by first significant letters in the units :) Just lowercase to xMbits and probably you'll get what you want.

man ipfw

```
bw bandwidth | device
             Bandwidth, measured in [K|M]{bit/s|Byte/s}.
```

Comment: Thank you @Kondybas!
The big 'M' was the culprit. Now it's working correctly. Only the time to establish a connection is very long ;-)

Comment: @TheLostOne Big "B" was a culprit. IPFW treats MB* as MBytes and Mb* as Mbits. So when you declare MBits, IPFW make a decision about units by two first letters.

Comment: Yeah, the big "B" was the reason. Sorry. Somehow mixed up 'M' and 'B' in the above comment :D